# Twilio VoiceBase High Accuracy Transcription download using PHP

Tags: twilio

I am using VoiceBase High Accuracy Transcription addon . I need to download the trascripted text using PHP. After i gave webhook URL , i got a success response with payload URLs.

But, how can i download transcript file in PHP using those information.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this script at your webhook URL

```
<?php

    //First collectand parse JSON from Twilio POST
    $twilio_response_payload = $_POST["AddOns"];
    $twilio_response_payload = json_decode($twilio_response_payload, true);

    //Grab the VoiceBase Data url
    $url = $twilio_response_payload['results']['voicebase_transcription']['payload'][0]['url'];


    $twilio_account_sid = "your-Twilio-sid";
    $twilio_auth_token = "your-Twilio-Auth-Token";


     //Send a GET with basic auth

        set_time_limit(0);
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_LIMIT, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_TIME, 60);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 300);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $twilio_account_sid . ":" . $twilio_auth_token);  
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

      //Response is of xml form that contains an s3 url, extract the s3 url. I manipulate the string, there is probably a cleaner way.

      $s3url = substr($response, strpos($response, "<RedirectTo>") + 12, strpos($response, "</RedirectTo>") - strpos($response, "<RedirectTo>") - 12);            
      $s3url = html_entity_decode($s3url);


      //Make another curl to that s3 url

        set_time_limit(0);
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_LIMIT, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_TIME, 60);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 300);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $s3url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);              

      //The response will be some JSON, parse the JSON

      $json_response = json_decode($response,true);

      //Media > Transcripts > Text is the plain text transcript, create a file or do whatever you like with it

      $text = $json_response['media']['transcripts']['text'];

      $file = 'transcription.txt';
      file_put_contents($file, $text);

  ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for ur quick reply